# How to get all most common eclipse sources?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Often I need to see a source code of some eclipse class on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or find a class or file by 'File search' on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Some classes are found, but most of needed classes not. Most often I do not know, which plugin the class is in. So I need to get sources of common eclipse plugins.

I found [Java Source Attacher](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-source-attacher) plugin, but it attaches only java libraries code.

I found [Eclipse Git Repositories](http://git.eclipse.org/c/), but I did not understand, how to download this sources. I could not find, which link to use to set it in `git clone` command. And there are separate plugins here.

I found [GrepCode repository](http://repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/), but here need to download source code by plugins or watch the code online.

I want just to download most common sources and import it to a separate project 'Eclipse sources'.

How to attach most common eclipse plugins sources to the workspace and where to find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 'Help > Install New Software' select (or enter) the updates site for your release - this is a different site from the normal releases site. For Eclipse Neon it is `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6`

Install the 'SDK' entries for the source you want, probably 'Eclipse Platform SDK' and 'Eclipse SDK'.

Once that is installed open the Preferences and in 'Plug-in Development' select the 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search' option.

Other parts of Eclipse such as Web Tools have there own update sites containing their source (`http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/neon/` for Web Tools).